# Некоторые нюансы кода на Delphi

Tags: delphi

Имеется листинг программы ( не мой, признаюсь сразу) :)

Я человек не слишком близкий к программированию, а делфи, если честно в 1 раз имею дело с таким кодом. Посидев, подумав, почитай... Разобрался во всем, почти.
Но есть некоторые вопросы, будьте так добры подскажите?

1. Какие библиотеки тут используются?
2. Если ти тут допольнительные файлы с логами? Можно в коде это увидеть?
3. И как посмотреть в среде Borland Delphi 6 из сколько юнитов, состоит мой проект? 
    [листинг программы](http://codepaste.ru/13310/)

Извиняюсь за глупые вопросы, но они меня почему-то ввели в ступор.

Comment: А вот 3-й вопрос отпадает, разобрался)

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Библиотеки  **Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Controls, Forms,
   Dialogs, ComCtrls, TeEngine, ExtCtrls, TeeProcs, StdCtrls,
   Menus, tlhelp32, Grids, registry;**

2 Логирование не ведется.

3 В данном случае юнит один, он основной называется taskkiller.

По сути у вас диспетчер задач своеобразный написан.

Comment: Дада, спасибо. Именно диспетчер.

У меня 2 юниту, вот первый здесь и 2-й отвечает за добавление новой задачи.

Насчет логирования спасибо.

Comment: 1. VCL + виндовые kernel32.dll и т.д. Плюс какие-то компоненты типа TeEngine (хотя может это и модуль программы).
3. еще есть unit cmd как минимум.

Comment: Ах да еще вопрос? У меня есть функция перезагрузки, выключения ПК, это API? Если да, то где именно в листинге это указано?

Comment: вот тут вызывается ExitWindowsEx(EWX_REBOOT,0); перегрузка винды.
API функция ExitWindowsEx параметры (EWX_REBOOT,0)

Comment: @Savro, спасбо тебе огромное)

Comment: Блин все понял и снова вопрос, где можно найти информацию о моих библиотеках на Delphi? Вкратце хотябы(

Comment: Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, ComCtrls,ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, Menus, tlhelp32, Grids, registry;
Это стандартные библиотеки Делфей, код их можеш посмотреть зажав контрол и кликнув по имени.
а остальные ищи в интернете, по имени должны нагуглится